# How to fetch data(like news article containing url, inkwell objects and string) from firebase into flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have stored a news article content into firebase [as shown here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ufdEcD4U3jAiQH4m4HSBkXzqSI9lcBRT/view?usp=sharing)

P.S- Here links in curly braces attach to text preceding it.

Here is my code to fetch it where "Content" is my field-

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Insights")
            .orderBy("Time", descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Inkwell(
                      child: Text(
                    (snapshot.data.docs[index]['Content'])
                        .toString()
                        .replaceAll("\\n", "\n"),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  )),
                );
              });
        });
  }
}
```

I am getting the output as simple text. While I want to show data on flutter application as [shown here output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GXEyhNNKt6SYSC0WuhiSIc91239juvhT/view?usp=sharing)

P.S - Blue color texts are clickable strings which will redirect to links attached as shown in input data in curly braces.

How can I achieve this? Is there any way to store data in firebase so that I can get output as shown in output image or is there any way to handle it in flutter application?

Answer (score 0):

Check this, `RichText` class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

You have to parse string and obtain the text with link and create `RichText` widget accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for response. But how RichText will format the text? Is there any way to store richtext in firebase , so that we can format it on runtime.

Comment: No need to store everything in firebase,
You have stored data with specific format (for url) is fine.
You need to parse the string and identify the portion of URL and create `TextSpan` and add in `children` of `RichText` dynamically.